# Source code for Docker Swarm load balancer

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

This question is quite code-specific rather than concept explanation.

I want to study how Docker Swarm's embedded DNS and Load Balancer is implemented, especially the roundrobin part.

I tried searching in [Docker github repo](https://github.com/docker/docker) with some keywords such as "loadbalancing", "balancer", "roundrobin" etc. but no result.

I found [Docker libnetwork](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork) that has keyword `RoundRobin` but I don't know how it is used in Docker engine.

Can anyone please help me to point out which files I should look at?

Answer (score 0):

You should search for `ingress`, Also try following 2 files:

```
docker/daemon/network.go
docker/api/types/swarm/network.go
```

Comment: I tried looking at results for "ingress", and especially 2 files you mentioned, but I don't find the part where it does the "roundrobin" stuff. Can you tell me in what files the "roundrobin" loadbalancing strategy is implemented?